# ruby script to read data over port 4001

Tags: ruby, sockets, port, telnet

At work, we purchased a package of sensors that count items as they pass down a conveyor belt. The sensors' information is accessible via the following protocol:

> XL Series Products use a binary protocol for Ethernet communication.
>   By default, the protocol is available on port 4001. (This is a
>   configurable property.)

I'd like to write a ruby script that periodically reads this data, but so far, I haven't even figured out how to access the data.

I played around with telnet and tested a simple client script in ruby, both of which left me pretty much where I started.

Does anyone have any information that could help?

Comment: Can you say more about what you tried with telnet and/or ruby?  what did and didn't work?  Were you able to get the binary data from the port, or were you not able to get anything at all from the port?

Comment: I tried this: `telnet 206.XXX.244.XXX 4001` but I didn't get any binary data.

Comment: I would think that you would want to confirm that you're getting a successful response with a simple telnet test before you try to do anything with ruby.  It seems like you need to debug why you aren't getting any response from whatever is listening at port 4001 first.

Comment: I can connect to the port with telnet, but I'm unsure how to send commands in hex. the docs say this: `Example
Command + Data (in hex) Command Description Response (in hex)
10 00 05 01 Read the User Number 1 value. 02 10 00 C8 00 00 00
`, but I don't know how to send those commands...

Comment: then i think your question would be more accurately described as "how to send commands using a binary protocol with ruby (or telnet)" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it supports Ethernet communication, try to use Socket provided in Ruby Standard Library.

Check :http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html